# Acessing other services through apache webserver

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I use debian 10 server and
I'm trying to configure apache webserver such that it can be able to handle requests of some services on the server using webpath eg /service.
Forexample if I have a service running on port 1234, to access it I have to enter myserverip:1234 into the browser, my interest is I don't want to use port but instead something like myserverip/service.
I have tried to configure apache using proxypass and proxyreverse concept in the proxy.conf module. The service tends to load but then just stops without completely loading the user interface.
What could be resulting into that and if there's any other method I can do that please share will be so grateful, thanks.
Thanks

Comment: Could you share your current mod_proxy config please? Did you already try to change the timeout setting (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout)?

Comment: Do you get any errors, check in the browser using developer/network tool. Do you see any 4XX codes? Pass the configuration, and full path to it. I there something interesting in apache log files? What is the _"service"_?